# Peaks in error during training - Regression problem with DL model (LSTM)

Tags: regression, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, training-error

During training I get unusual behavior of my model. Peaks show up in the both validation and training errors that I could not understand. I use MSE as a loss [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQcTx.png) and similar behavior appears in other metrics MAE [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKMlA.png) and MPAE [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQmQR.png).

I am using Deep LSTM model to do regression to approximate another function (time sequence -> real value). It is a determenistic function with no noise (thus no overfitting should appears). The function is costful to execute hence the usefulness of ML model to approximate it. **Data set :** Input = ~45000 Time Series (Sequence length = 60, features = 14) - Output = One real value for each sequence (~45000 real values).

Similar behavior when changing model complexity (parameters number). **Peaks are more significants when model is more complex (deeper and/or bigger).** I used model with params number between 500k to 3M.

1. How harmful is this to my model ?
   *For example, i can not determine when to stop training it will always be after several epochs (=patience if early stopping is used) from the peak.*
2. What are possible interpretations ? *Wrong loss function or extra layer*
3. What are the possible solutions to avoid this ? *Smaller LSTM layers gives higher error on test set*

[image: Loss]
[image: MAE]
[image: MPAE]